# Ios Swift : Remove duplicates in an array of images

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage, duplicates

I have an array of images. User can add other images to this array picking from photo gallery. So when ever they add, I want check if that image is already present and if present, I need to skip adding that.

I tried below But does not work on Image array

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable
{
    mutating func GetDifAryFnc()
    {
        var DifAryVar:[Element] = []
        for IdxVal in self
        {
            if !DifAryVar.contains( IdxVal )
            {
                DifAryVar.append( IdxVal )
            }
        }
        self = DifAryVar
    }
}
```

and Tried This

```
class func GetDifImjAryFnc(ImjAryPsgVar: [UIImage]) -> [UIImage]
{
    var DifAryVar = [UIImage]()
    for IdxVal in ImjAryPsgVar
    {
        if !DifAryVar.contains( IdxVal )
        {
            DifAryVar.append( IdxVal )
        }
    }

    return DifAryVar
}
```

Comment: Method and variable names in Swift should use lower camel case.

Comment: How do you qualify two images as being equal? Did they come from the same file? Do they have the same pixels?

Comment: Removing duplicates is really commonly covered. Have you searched first?

Comment: `{` on a new line, upper camel case, needless abbreviating `Index` to `Idx` (wooo 2 characters saved?). C# programmer, easy to spot.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the image is already present?" Are these images that are loaded from disk "as-is"? If you use the Array `contains` method, the images must be byte-for-byte identical in order to match. If even 1 pixel is different, or if they are JPEG compressed at different times, they will likely not match.

(The `Array` `contains` method relies on the objects conforming to the `equatable` protocol, which I believe checks the byte-wize hashes on the image data.)

### EDIT:

Actually, this article from Apple implies that the equatable comparison for UIImage objects may not work correctly:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage (see the part titled "Comparing Images")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *your* measure of equality is whatever is provided by Apple's implementation of `UIImage` conformance to the `Equatable` protocol, then why not use a `Set` instead of an `Array`?

```
let image1 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "stack_view")
let image2 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "stack_view")
let image3 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "stack_view2")

if image1.isEqual(image2) {
    print("We are the same!") // Prints We are the same!
} else {
    print("We are different!")
}

var images = Set<UIImage>()
images.insert(image1)
images.insert(image2) // No effect since the same image is already in the set
images.insert(image3)

images.count // The count is 2 (not 3)
```

If your measure of equality is something *different* than Apple's implementation (which we can assume is based on comparing the image data*), then you will have to specify this.

*Apple's `UIImage` documentation shows the correct way of comparing instances of `UIImage` using the `isEqual(_:)` method instead of the `==` operator.

**EDIT:**

If you have to use arrays, then you can create an extension like this:

```
extension Array where Element: UIImage {
    func unique() -> [UIImage] {
        var unique = [UIImage]()
        for image in self {
            if !unique.contains(image) {
                unique.append(image)
            }
        }
        return unique
    }
}
```

This will return an array that contains unique `UIImage` elements.

Comment: What's your read on what the equatable protocol implementation for UIImage uses internally? If it uses isEqual then the contains: function should work correctly.

Comment: @DuncanC I think the `Equatable` protocol implementation is the same as `isEqual(_:)` under the covers. I agree that `contains(_:)` should work correctly based on this thinking. Therefore writing a method that checks if the array already contains an `UIImage` using `contains(_:)` should be viable.